# Rails 5.1 CSS background image id not loading?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

So i've been adding a background image to my main page, however, the background image never loads.

application.scss file:

```
#background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background: url(background.jpg);
  background-size: cover; 
}
```

Now, adding the same line background: url(background.jpg); to the body, will work:

```
body {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 .05rem .1rem rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  background: url(background.jpg);
}
```

So this works, but when i add the background image to the #background tag it doesn't? Why is that so? Here's the application.html.erb file, where i call the #background id:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title><%= @page_title %></title>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>


        <!-- Load in the stylesheet file 'application.scss' -->
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
        <!-- Load in the javascript file 'application.js' -->
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

      </head>


      <body>
        <div class="site-wrapper">
          <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
            <div class="cover-container">

            <div id="background"></div>



            <!-- Alerts for devise -->
            <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
            <p class="alert"><%= alert%></p>


            <!-- Render the nav bar from the shared folder -->
            <%= render "shared/application_nav"%>


            <!-- Yield content -->
            <%= yield %>

            <!-- Render footer from the shared folder -->
            <%= render "shared/footer"%>

            <!-- Load in Gemfile for the Copyright Logo -->
            <%= source_helper %>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Changing the  tag to the bottom didn't change anything. Using variations of background-image, image-url, url('background.jpg'); instead didn't helped either.

The -webkit-transform etc. is all working from the #background id.

Any ideas what would cause that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks! I've tried it out but still the image didn't showed up, even when i changed the div's height / width (which i did before), the image still weren't visible. It was some bug, since changing the name of the id/class to some other name finally fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1 - most the time it depend on your content inside your `<div>`

2 - otherways you can setup your Height and width to 100%
      then add this lines down your (`#background`) :

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-color:orange;
background-position: center center;
background-size: auto auto;
```

so it become :

```
#background {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  z-index: -100;

  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background: url(background.jpg);

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-color:orange;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: auto auto;

}
```

see the : [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dBRQw/52/)

> of course you can change (background-color) value as you like to fi your style
>   and if you want the width to be increase based on your `<div` content then just remove `width: 100%; height: 100%;` or set them manual to any size u want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in your syntax but your division is empty. If you add some content to that division then the background image will appear,
or give the actual height of the image instead of auto.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! On the bottom, i mentioned that putting something inside the div, for example, the yield or whatever is under the div background id, doesn't change anything. Changing height, width didn't helped either.

Answer (score 0):

So it seemed like there was some bug going on. After changing the id to a class and rename it to some gibberish like test123 it finally worked. I've doubled checked if there is already an id/class that is called background in my scss file (im using a template from bootstrap 4) but haven't found any.

Anyway's, still thank you for your time and suggestions!

EDIT: Actually, the issue was the following:

```
#background{


}
```

works fine,

```
#background {


}
```

not. Notice the space between the first bracket and background. I guess java / jquery gem is messing with my scss or something, but deleting the space finally fixed it completely.